# Как выбрать объект Image из файла PDF средствами библиотеки iText, если файл искажен?

Tags: java, pdf, itext

В общем, задача такая: есть косвенный объект, например, 13 0 obj, в словаре которого значится Image. На содержимое потока наложен фильтр FlateDecode.
Как средствами библиотеки iText можно выбрать это изображение и сохранить в файле?  Файл PDF искажен, и объект класса PdfReader создать невозможно. Можно только передать содержимое словаря объекта и поток, например, в виде массива байт или строки.

Answer (score 0):

В худшем случае, вы всегда можете обработать файл PDF как byte[]. Обычно потоки помечаются как `stream` и `endstream`. Аналогично, объекты помеченные `13 0 obj` и `endobj`.

После того, как у вас есть byte[], который представляет ваше изображение, вы можете использовать iText (в частности, `FlateDecode`), чтобы вернуть исходные байты изображения.